# Host Existing WCF Service On Azure

Tags: .net, wcf, azure

I have a very simple wcf application made up of App.config, Iservice.cs, Service,cs and Service.svc.  I simply publish this to IIS and end up with bin directory with my DLLs, a web.config (Dervied from app.config) and my .svc file which is what is browsed to to access the service.

I want to move this to Azure but am not sure sure the simplest way.  I have created a new Windows Azure Project in vs2010 but I can't add my existing project as a role and instead i'm forced to create a new web role or wcf service role.

Can anyone tell me what I have to change to host my existing project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just open your WCF Web project, right click on it and select:

Add Windows Azure Deployment Project:

[image: Add Windows Azure Deployment Project]

This will create the Cloud Service project for you, and will add your web app as a web role. It will only work if are using Web Application project, and not Web Site project.

Comment: Thanks - Unfortionaely I am using Web Site project. Anyway around this or should I just start again?

Comment: Web Role can only a WebApplication! There is a workaround to allow to deploy web site to Azure, but I strongly suggest that you convert to WebApplication if the project is not big and is the only web project in solution.

Comment: I just make this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733844/convert-existing-wcf-service-to-azure-wcf-service Im worried that once converted it won't work again in traditional IIS environment.