# How to deploy WCF in Windows Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, deployment, azure

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685515/host-existing-wcf-service-on-azure)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065682/changing-existing-wcf-project-to-azure-project) it is written how to convert a standard WCF Service to Windows Azure. It is written, that after right-click you will have an option to *"Add Windows Azure Deployment Project"*. But still I do not see it in Visual Studio in my project after right-click at the WCF Application project.

This is the screenshot:

[image: Screen shot]

What is wrong? How to deploy it in Windows Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in the other post this should normally work. But since it does not I propose copying over your WCF interfaces, classes and configurations to a brand new WCF Service Role project. Then you will be able to publish it to Windows Azure directly without any problems.

Comment: Just move over the code to a new WCF Service Role project and test your service in the Windows Azure emulator. If everything works fine you may then publish via the "Publish" command in Visual Stuidio to Windows Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following link [Code Quick Start: Create and deploy a WCF service in Windows Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy/)

Comment: Url doesn't exist anymore :(