# Convert existing WCF Service to Azure WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, azure

I have a `WCF services` web project that runs in a dedicated server.

Because of customer requirements we need to move forward Azure cloud.

In Visual Studio I found this option when I right click in my WCF project.

[image]

My question is:

> Once converted to Azure Cloud Service Project can I still host that WCF Service in a local environment (IIS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once converted to Azure Cloud Service Project can I still host that WCF Service in a local environment (IIS)?

You could migrate your web application to an Azure Cloud Service via VS. Per my understanding, it would create the new Azure Cloud Service and add your WCF project as the WCF Service Web Role. For more details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service).

You could [Enable Remote Desktop Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop) for your web role and connect to your remote role server, then you could find your web application hosted on the IIS Manager as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To shortly answer the question whether you could still host the WCF on-premise in IIS:

YES. You still can. That "Convert Azure Cloud Service" project, as Bruce Chen already explained does not alter your original project in any way. The process just adds one new project to your solution - the Azure Cloud Service Project and reference your WCF Service project as a WebRole for the Cloud Service. It makes the Cloud Service project the default startup project. There are no changes to your original WCF Service Project.